# Troubles with proxy in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, proxy

I recently started used ubuntu and i have some problems with it. 
In first, every time when i reboot ubuntu, the lines "https_proxy", "http_proxy" in the environment are overwritten to '127.0.0.1:8888' and i have trouble with my network until I deleted this value of proxy.

```
diffurchik@diffurchik:~$ env|grep http
https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
```

In second, if i try created command cURL or git then i get error: 
`Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused` (of course i'm trying input command after deleted proxy values in env)

P.S. And also in GUI network settings Network Proxy turn off

Comment: Did you try to reboot after turning off **Network Proxy** from Ubuntu Settings GUI? Also, try the following: `grep -i proxy ~/.bash*`

Comment: Yes, of course i rebooted my system a lot of times after shutdown gui network proxy